# Tapping small hole on titanium

Tags: machining, metals, cnc, alloys

So I want to tap a super small hole on grade 5 titanium alloy with M1.8x0.2 (which should be possible according to [this Quora's answer](https://www.quora.com/Can-you-add-a-thread-inside-a-2mm-diameter-hole-of-Ti-6Al-4V-How). But is there any tap available for me to do this job? I mean M1.8 with grade 5 titanium, the normal tap should break very easily. Since it's a super small hole with super tough material.

Also, can it be done by normal CNC, like the one you'll find in a normal company? Since the document looks like some scientific research which might be using some advanced machines. And can it be done on CNC engraving and milling machine or it needs a CNC lathe?

Last, why you should [tap titanium with CNC](https://www.mmsonline.com/articles/tips-for-tapping-titanium-alloys) but not by hand?

Comment: The material in the paper was additive manufactured, with no details about it's properties. So I wouldn't directly compare it to forged material. Also do you have any control on the heat treatment, or is it supplied in the treated condition? As tapping would be easiest between any solution and aging treatments.

Answer (score 3):

It should be doable by hand; the Quora answer missed what I found to be the most important factor for cutting Ti; use chlorinated cutting fluid like carbon tetra chloride. I once drilled small holes ( 1/8 ") in grade 2 or 3 ( lower strength more ductile than 5 ) ; I broke a bit ( high speed steel, not Home Depot) before making the first hole . I used the carbon tet and then drilled several holes . Not easy but not as tough as drilling 18-8 stainless.